# Query with condition isNotEqualTo not work in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem with the query with the condition isNotEqualTo does not work and does not show the values ​​checked from the condition, note that I tried the condition isNotEqualTo and it worked
What is the problem

```
_setStream() async {
    var pos = await location.getLocation();
    double lat = pos.latitude!;
    double lng = pos.longitude!;
    

    var ref = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('now')
     .where('uid', isNotEqualTo: _user.uid).orderBy('uid');

    GeoFirePoint center = geo.point(latitude: lat, longitude: lng);

    stream = radius.switchMap((rad) {
      var collectionReference = ref;
      return geo.collection(collectionRef: collectionReference).within(
          center: center, radius: rad, field: 'location', strictMode: true);
    });

    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });

    stream = geo.collection(collectionRef: ref).within(
        center: center, radius: 2000, field: 'location', strictMode: true);
    stream!.listen((List<DocumentSnapshot> documentList) {
      documentList.forEach((element) {
        print("from data .......element");
        print(element.data());
        final data = element.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
        final GeoPoint point = data['location']['geopoint'];
        print("from data .......latitude");
        print(point.latitude);
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: what is the value of _time?

Comment: I edit code now ----- change _time to _user.uid

Comment: Can you post the errors here please

Comment: there isn't error but the query not show values -- I don't want show my user in the query ---  I want query for users near me but I want it without my user

Comment: Flutter released not equal to query after a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though NotEqual query is available in firebase, it was made available late in flutter plugin. The best option is to fetch all to a list and remove unwanted elements from the list

Comment: how remove unwanted elements from the list when fetching

Comment: someList.removeWhere((item) => item.id == 'userid')

Comment: I use this code  data.removeWhere((key, value) => true); but this remove all data-- I want only delete one value from data type Map<String, dynamic>

Comment: What is the key and value that you are trying to remove..? The removeWhere will remove item based on a condition. In the example that i posted if item.id ==  'userid' it will remove it

Comment: key = 'uid' ,,, value = _user.uid  from firestore

Comment: var finalList = (await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('now')).removeWhere((item) => item.uid == 'userid'))